# Bootstrap: prevent panel from collapsing on checkbox click

Tags: html, checkbox, bootstrap-4, panel

So I've a panel heading which contains some text and a checkbox.
How do I prevent the panel from collapsing when I toggle the checkbox?

```
<div class="panel-heading panel-heading-fail">
    <div class="panel-title" data-target="#panel_body"
                             data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel_meta"
                             aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="pull-left">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        </span>
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Every time I toggle the checkbox it opens/closes the panel.
How can I prevent it from doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to help you?

Answer (score 0):

`pull-left` has been replaced in Bootstrap 4 with `float-left`, and when using `float-left` use a wrapper element with class="form-check" to ensure proper margins for labels and checkboxes. You can see I added the class "form-check" to the div surrounding your `<span>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-fail">
    <div class="panel-title form-check" data-target="#panel_body" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel_meta" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="float-left">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      </span>
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

> Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to the element to automatically assign control of one or more collapsible elements. The data-target attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the collapse to. Be sure to add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you’d like it to default open, add the additional class show.

That is from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes). Check it out.

Comment: Not sure how this solves my issue. The panel still opens/closes every time I click the checkbox.

Comment: I added to my answer. What are you trying to accomplish with `data-toggle="collapse"`? And `data-target="#panel_body"` references an element with an id of "panel_body", but there is no such element in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Move the input to outside the 'panel-title' and use a 'd-flex' div to keep it inline:

```
<div class="panel-heading panel-heading-fail">
  <div class='d-flex'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-chkbox form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <div class="custom-text panel-title" data-target="#panel_body" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel_meta" aria-expanded="true">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the 'custom-chkbox'/'custom-text' classes to adjust the checkbox and text as desired.